# Query in Rails to fetch from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a table Info(:name, :friend_id) and another table Friends(:id, :network). The attribute :network can be Facebook/Gmail/Linkedin. I want to count all my friends from all services like count of friends from FB, Gmail and Linkedin. I have a friends_list

```
friends_list = Info.where(:name => my_name)
```

I don't want to iterate over friends_list and find for each friend_id the normal way. Is there a single line query which can give me the count of all friends from Facebook?

Comment: `Info.joins(:friend).where(:name => my_name, network: 'Facebook').count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`#count`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#count) with [`#group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group), the query might need a little tweaking, but it's generally possible.

```
friends_counts = Friends.joins(:info).group(:network).where(infos: {name: my_name}).count
```

This should return an array of hashes, the hash key is the network id, and the hash value is the number of friends in that network.

Comment: This is not what I asked. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: so you want separate counts?